# How to display a UIAlertController when site is not allowed, using decidePolicyFor

Tags: ios, swift, mobile, webkit

I am going through Paul Hudson's Hacking with Swift tutorials and trying to get the `WebView` to display a `UIAlertController` when a site is not allowed. Right now, the sites allowed come from a hardcoded array.

I've already tried inserting the following right before the call to `decisionHandler(.cancel)` as well as adding it to the end of the `if host.contains(website)` statement:

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Heads Up!", message: "This URL is blocked.", preferredStyle: .alert)
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel))
present(alert, animated: true)
```

Here's the code:

```
var websites = ["apple.com", "hackingwithswift.com"]

func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
     let url = navigationAction.request.url

     if let host = url?.host {
         for website in websites {
             if host.contains(website) {
                 decisionHandler(.allow)
                 return
             }
         }
     }
  decisionHandler(.cancel)
}
```

I understand that there are only two sites a visitor can even visit - but it wouldn't be a challenge on Paul's site if it wasn't applicable. You can view my entire repo of this project here: https://github.com/andrewlundy/hacking-with-swift/tree/master/Project4

Comment: In the Sample Github project, UIAlertController is displayed. So, what is required?

Comment: It's displayed on a URL that is valid. It needs to be displayed on a URL that isn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After adding a `UITableViewController` as the initial `ViewController`, displaying the websites in a list and then checking if the current site is in the `ViewController` that is hosting the `WKWebView`, which has a property of `websites`, I was able to come up with a basic solution.

By using `didSelectRowAt` in the `UITableViewController` you can see that if the site the user tapped on is not in the websites that are allowed, it will now bring up an alert and let the user know that the site is blocked.

I believe this can be improved so you don't have to update both of the `websites` properties in each `ViewController` but this will do for the Hacking with Swift tutorial. Please add on to this answer if you can make this more efficient.

The new TableViewController class:

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

    let webView = ViewController()
    var websites = ["apple.com", "hackingwithswift.com", "facebook.com"]


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print(webView.websites)
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return websites.count
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "WebsiteCell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = websites[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let currentSite = websites[indexPath.row]
        webView.currentSite = currentSite

        if webView.websites.contains(currentSite) {
            navigationController?.pushViewController(webView, animated: true)
        } else {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Heads Up!", message: "This URL is blocked", preferredStyle: .alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { (UIAlertAction) in
                self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
            }))
            present(alert, animated: true)
        }
    }
}
```